# Using callbacks in a non-async-context

Tags: google-maps, ember.js

I have a service with a method called "`getGmapsDistance()`". Here im using the google maps api to get the distance between an origin an an destination.

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({

  getShortestDistanceInMeters: function(location) {

    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    service.getDistanceMatrix({
      ...
    }, this.callback); //<<<<<< !!!

  },

  callback: function(response, status) {
      ....
  }
});
```

In my controller if got a array with locations and now I want to iterate over it and want check each element if the distance is <= the max destination.

```
locationsNearby: Ember.computed('locations', function() {
     //...
     var filteredResult = [];

      locations.forEach(function(locat) {
        if (this.get('distanceService').getShortestDistanceInMeters(locat) <= maxDistance) {
          filteredResult.pushObject(locat);
        }
      });

      return filteredResult;
})
```

Unfortunately the GMaps API for distance calculation uses a callback so the request is async.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: You could return a promise from the `getShortestDistanceInMeters` method, checkout [Ember.RSVP.resolve](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.html#method_resolve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not make an async call synchronous! This is an javascript language limitation and is important to understand! Javascript has only one thread, so this can't be changed by a library or so!

The *fancy new way* to handle callbacks are Promises.
You **really really** should checkout the [specifications](https://promisesaplus.com)!
It's one of the most beautiful specifications you will ever read!

Ember uses Promises heavily! For example a routes `model` hook waits for a Promise to resolve before going on with the transition.

In your case you want to update the computed property when the promise resolves. Because ember-data causes this to happen often they provide two fancy classes: PromiseObject and PromiseArray. A computed property depending on a computed property that returns a PromiseObject/Array will recompute when the promise resolves:

```
locationsNearby: Ember.computed('locations', {
    get() {
        let promise = Ember.RSVP.all(this.get('locations').map(location => Ember.RSVP.hash(({
            location,
            distance: this.get('distanceService').getShortestDistanceInMeters(location)
        })))).then(hashs => hashs.filter(hash => hash.distance <= maxDistance).map(hash => hash.location));

        return DS.PromiseArray.create({promise});
    }
})
```

To explain it a little:

I build an array with hash's of the location and a promise to the distance:

```
let locationsWithDistancePromise = this.get('locations').map(location => {
  distance: this.get('distanceService').getShortestDistanceInMeters(location),
  location
})
```

Then I use `RSVP.hash` on all of them to get an array of promises that will resolve to an array of hashes with distance and location:

```
let hashPromiseArr = locationsWithDistancePromise.map(h => Ember.RSVP.hash(h));
```

Now I use `Ember.RSVP.all` to get an promise that will resolve to an array of hashes with location and distance:

```
let hashArrPromise = Ember.RSVP.all(hashPromiseArr);
```

An finally I `.then` on the promise and filter the nearby locations. Also I map the hash to a array of locations.

```
let promise = hashArrPromise.then(hashs => {
  return hashs.filter(hash => hash.distance <= maxDistance)
    .map(hash => hash.location);
});
```

And wrap it as an PromiseArray

```
return DS.PromiseArray.create({promise});
```

---

You can just loop over this Computed Property from handlebars with `{{#each}}` or use it in another Computed Property:

```
allNearbyLocations: Ember.computed('locationsNearby.[]', {
    get() {
        return this.get('locationsNearby').toArray().join(' - ');
    }
}
```

---

Of course you need to rewrite `getShortestDistanceInMeters` so that it returns a Promise:

```
getShortestDistanceInMeters(location) {
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
          //...
        }, (response, status) => {
            if(status.error) {
                reject(response);
            } else {
                resolve(response);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Lux  for that big approach, but i think it wont work: As far I can see, their is no "waiting"-mechanism for the getShortestDistanceInMeters-function (since it will return instantly "nothing" and just the async-callback function will have the answer from google). So in you solution, the promise will be fulfilled instantly since its return will not include the result from the api request. Am I right?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Of course you have to rewrite `getShortestDistanceInMeters` so it returns a Promise.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was VERY helpfull so far! But it is still not working 100%. In my then, a console.out is working but not in the template. Please look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/MarcManhart/b77a3d09d22990bbf812 can you help me with that last part one more time? :)

Comment: You have a missing `return` in line 21. Or omit the curly brackets. Because `x => 1` returns 1 and is identical to `x => { return 1 }` but `x => { 1 }` will return `undefined`! And you need the `PromiseArray` to make an iterable array to loop in the `handlebars` template. A PromiseArray is first an empty array and later will update to the resolved array.

Comment: You sir, are awesome! Thanks a lot, really @Lux!